# GridView row as link, except action column items in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

When i use the below code it overrides the action-column delete/update links.

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
    return [
        'id'      => $model['id'], 
        'onclick' => 'location.href="' 
            . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('accountinfo/update') 
            .'?id="+(this.id);',
    ];
},
```

As I have many columns it would be good to specify link url in one place instead of using the below code in each column:

```
 'value' => function ($data) {
                return Html::url('site/index');
            }
```

So is there any best way to give link for whole row in GridView except action column?

**EDIT: 
Full Gridview**

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
    'rowOptions'   => function ($model, $index, $widget, $grid) {
        if ($widget == 1)
            return [
                'id' => $model['id'], 
                'onclick' => 'location.href="'
                    . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('accountinfo/update') 
                    . '?id="+(this.id);'
            ];
    },
    'columns'      => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        // 'id',
        'f_name',
        'l_name',
        'address',
        'country',
        'state',
        'city',
        'pincode',
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return $model->status == '1' ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
            },
            'filter'    => [1 => 'Enabled', 0 => 'Disabled'],
        ],
        'card',
        'note',
        'balance',
        'is_new',
        [
            'attribute' => 'is_new',
            'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return $model->is_new == '1' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
            },
            'filter'    => [1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'],
        ],
        [
            'class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{update}&nbsp;&nbsp;{delete}',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Could you explain it with more details? Add full `GridView` rendering code. Maybe provide some example. I don't get it, why it's needed?

Comment: added my grid view.. I want to redirect it to update page when the row is clicked. The problem is when i click the delete button it gets redirected to update page due to that **rowOptions**

Comment: Btw: The parameter of rowOptions in 'Full GridView' are not correct. It should be ($model, $key, $index, $grid) instead of ($model, $index, $widget, $grid).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try this. It will make the whole row clickable as long as the user clicks on a td element that is not covered from another element. So also the action column is part of the clickable row, however, not the glyphicons.

```
<?= GridView::widget([

    ...

    'rowOptions'   => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
        return ['data-id' => $model->id];
    },

    ...

]); ?>

<?php
$this->registerJs("

    $('td').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
        if(e.target == this)
            location.href = '" . Url::to(['accountinfo/update']) . "?id=' + id;
    });

");
```

See also documentation for [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

> The target property can be the element that registered for the event
>   or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to
>   this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event
>   bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when
>   events bubble.

Comment: As @MaciejStrączkowski noted: you might want to test if `id` is `undefined` in your javascript otherwise any clicks on search- and header rows will redirect to a view with `id=undefined`, which is annoying and makes search impossible.

Comment: Or you could just narrow your js identifier down to 'tbody td'

Comment: Yii2 adds the primary key into the row anyway so you can do away with 'rowOptions'=>...... and use  var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('key');

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using below javascript to prevent event triggering on filter columns.

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("
    $('td').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
        if (e.target == this && id)
            location.href = '" . Url::to(['thread/view']) . "?id=' + id;
    });
");
```

**Or**

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("
    $('tbody td').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('tbody td').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
        if (e.target == this)
            location.href = '" . Url::to(['thread/view']) . "?id=' + id;
    });
");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    'attribute'=>'website',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value'=>function ($data) {
    $wsite = Agents::find()
             ->all();
    return Html::a(Html::encode($wsite[0]->website), $wsite[0]->website);
     },
    'label'=>'Website',
    'vAlign'=>'middle',
    'width'=>'150px',             
],
```

Answer (score 0):

User `'filterPosition'=>'  ',`

```
<?=
                    GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                        'resizableColumns' => true,
                        'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
                        'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
                        'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
                        'pjax' => true,
                        'hover' => true,
                        'export' => false,
                        'columns' => $gridColumns,
                        'filterPosition'=>' ',
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $filterModel,
        'rowOptions' => function ($m, $key, $index, $grid) {
            return ['data-href' => 'book-vgift/girl-vgift?to=' . $m->user_id];
        },
        'columns' => [
            [
```

JavaScript file

```
$('table tr[data-href]').click(function () {

    if ($(this).data('href') !== undefined) {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me from these solutions except:

```
echo GridView::widget([
   ...
   'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
        return [
            'style' => "cursor: pointer",
            'myurl' => ['/route','id'=>$model->id],
        ];
    }
    ...
```

And the Javascript piece:

```
$this->registerJs("
    $('tbody tr[myurl]').click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('td')) {
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('myurl');
        } 
    });
");
```

Don't now why the other solutions did not work but maybe this solution helps someone before wasting time for hours - as in my case :-(

Answer (score 0):

please use this function:

```
$(document).on('click','td', function(e) {
               var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
               if(e.target == this)
                   location.href = id;
 });
```

Otherwise pagination with Pjax will break your links!

Answer (score 0):

Use : rowOptions

```
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'layout' => "{summary}\n<div class='table table-responsive list-table'>{items}\n</div><div class='text-center'>{pager}</div>",
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
        return ['data-id' => $model->id];
    },
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn', 'contentOptions' => ['width' => '']],
        'name',
        'email',
        [
            'class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'disable-click'],
            'header' => "Actions",
            'template' => '{update}&nbsp;&nbsp;{delete}',
        ],
        ],
]);
?>

<?php
$this->registerJs("
    $('tbody td:not(.disable-click)').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $(document).on('click','table tr td:not(.disable-click)',function(e) {      
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
        if (e.target == this && id)
            location.href = '" . Url::to(['/contacts/view']) . "?id=' + id;
    });
");
?>
```