# How to add onclick event on certain columns only with Yii2 Gridview rowOptions

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii2

I have a gridview and enabled only Delete button in ActionColumn. There is no problem when I try to click the `ok` from the confirm box when the delete button is pressed. The problem is when `cancel` button is pressed in confirmation. What happens is, it redirects the page depending on the url returned by rowOptions.

```
             [
              'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'template' => '{delete}',
             ],
        ],
            'rowOptions' => function($model, $index, $attribute) {
                    $url = "whatever url"

                    if ($index > 0) {
                        return [
                            'onclick' => "window.location.href='{$url}'",
                            'style' => 'cursor:pointer'
                        ];
                    }
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand  what's happen exactly..(an error, an unaspected result... other)  if is possibile use an example ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Hi! sorry for the trouble. For example, I press the delete button inside the gridview, if I pressed `OK` on the confirm box then `actionDelete` is called which is right. The problem is when I press `Cancel` on the confirm box, instead of closing only the confirm box and staying at the current page, I am redirected to whatever url is assigned on its `rowOptions`

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28381221/57091) help you?

Comment: almost but how can i pass hidden columns?

Comment: Seem you want redefine delete ... but if so..and just for curiosity why you are using rowsOptions for this  .. and not urlCreator in actionColumn.. ?