# How to make row in gridview clickable?

Tags: redirect, gridview, yii2, row, yii2-advanced-app

I am very new to yii2. I have created a gridview using CRUD Generator. I want to make the gridview's rows to be clickable like when we click on view. It should navigate to the  view page for that row.

My gridview code is as follows:

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'Task_ID',
        'Task_Title',
        'Description',
        //'employee.employee_name',
        //'Assign_task_to',
        'start_date',
         'due_date',
         'priotiy_level',
        // 'complexity_level',
        // 'upload_documents',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView row as link, except action column items in Yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381221/gridview-row-as-link-except-action-column-items-in-yii2)

Comment: I tried using that but the always gave me an undefined id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

below code added `Task_Title` as clickable:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           [
                    'attribute'=>'Task_Title',
                    'format'=>'raw',
                    'value' => function($data)
                    {
                        return
                        Html::a($data->Task_Title, ['task/view','id'=>2], ['title' => 'View','class'=>'no-pjax']);
                    }
            ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: The id doesn't change. I want the id to change dynamically :(

Comment: ['task/view','id'=>$data-> your_id] add id like this

Comment: You want: 'id' => $data->id

Comment: @user2211486 this code worked for you.pls upvote and approve this answer  its useful for others.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'rowOptions' => function($model,$index,$key){
     
      return ['id' => $model['id'], 'onclick' => 'alert("Row clicked")'];           
 
  }
    
'columns' => [] ]); ?>
```

Comment: For the record - $model in the most cases is ActiveRecord and you should call the parameter as object's property not as a array key.

Comment: I agree @SergeiSergeev